# how to fix Javascript function error saying expected ';'?

Tags: list, javascript

I use below code to create a Barchart on my sharepoint page. I checked the code online and all is fine, still while running it says ";" expected at ---> let barchart = new Chart("barChart", {
Does it mean 'let' is not working?

```
 function fnGenerateChart(xValues, yValues) {
     let barChart = new Chart("barChart", {
         type: "bar",
         data: {
             labels: xValues,
             datasets: [{
                 data: yValues,
                 label: 'Reply on the RFI',
                 backgroundColor: barColors
             }]
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Check if you are missing any closing `}` bracket in your code. Also, try using `var` instead of `let`. let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried var instead of let but then I get an error saying 'Chart' is undefined

Comment: Try using `const` then. Refer example given [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html).

Comment: Now its telling me syntax error! at this line:
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

Comment: Is this function inside another file or script, It may be that this piece of code is not wrong, but the script this code is a part of has errors

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. It turned out that I was missing a reference to a .js file